# Upload with JavaScript using Firebase Storage and Dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-storage, dropzone.js

I have been doing a lot of research and have yet to find a viable solution for the following. I asked a [more specific question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591122/firebase-storage-and-dropzone-js-multiple-image-upload-on-button-press)) but due to the lack of answers or comments, I decided to ask a more generalized question that may be applicable to more people.

Anyway, dropzone.js allows you to create a file upload with js. Below is a snippet of code that does just that:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
  url: "/" // Not sure what to put here...
});
```

Where the url: "" would be equivalent to the `action=""` in a form. Most examples you can find have url: "upload.php" however I am trying to upload the images to firebase. Is there a way to run js for the file upload instead of php? perhaps url: "upload.js"? That wouldn't work but just to show what I mean. Or is there a way to upload images to Firebase with PHP? I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Here is what dropzone.js says about the URL attribute, I just don't understand it fully:

> URL: *Has to be specified on elements other than form (or when the
> form doesn't have an action attribute). You can also provide a
> function that will be called with files and must return the url (since
> v3.12.0)*

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload directly to Firebase Storage via some special URL that you can put in a web form.  But you can easily implement an endpoint with Cloud Functions for Firebase with a little extra code you write that runs on the server side.

I have [a short Gist that gives all the code](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/90ce5a6983fdee10c415eb2a93917e02) that makes it happen.

You can watch the code in action [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/CodingDoug/status/945035556555186176).

I hosted my web site via Firebase Hosting, but if you don't do that, you may need to set up CORS or something to be able to call from your page to Cloud Functions.

Comment: Actually, you can upload directly to firebase as seen here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files. I just don't know how to trigger js with dropzone, and the url: "" is supposed to be how you do it. I just added an image to the question if you could take a look but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: FYI, it's customary to copy text directly into the question instead of requiring people to click through to an image to see it.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack and don't have the reputation to put them inline. StackOverflow told me I couldn't do that until a reach a 10 reputation. I'll update it when I can, sorry!

Comment: Just copy the text into the question.

Comment: Do you mean like this? Check out the recent edit please.

Comment: Do you know what they mean when they say calling a function? do i just say url: imageUpload(files) where files is an array or list?

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem, that dropzone.js needs an URL to upload the dropped files.
This could be handled with an HTTP trigger firebase function. But this is not was is happening in the gist from @DougStevenson.